# PHP Echo just one the item from the array, if reload do not echo

Tags: php, html

I have an array of values with PHP, Is it possible that when the user first reloads the page, the value should be echoed, but If he reloads the same page again, It should not output two of the same values.

```
foreach($_SESSION['arrayFolders'] as $value){
    if (in_array($_SESSION['arrayFolders'], $value)) {
        echo 'Do not reload the page, we have already greeted you :)';
    } else {
        echo 'Welcome!';
    }
```

What I am trying to do with the IF condition is, if the value is already on the session array do not echo it.

NOTE: When the user first enters on the page, he generates an array called `$_SESSION['arrayFolders']`.

Any questions feel free to ask.

EDIT 1:

Reverse the `in_array` method.

```
...

$_SESSION['arrayFolders'][] = '<a>folder/folder2</a>';

...


foreach($_SESSION['arrayFolders'] as $value){
    if (in_array($value, $_SESSION['arrayFolders'])) {
        echo 'Welcome';
        //Here I should delete the value from the string so that It does not loop again.
    }
```

Comment: How can it not be in the array, since you're looping over that array?

Comment: And your [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) parameters are the wrong way round.

Comment: You're not echoing any values from the array, you're just echoing specific strings.

Comment: Please show how you place information into the SESSION array

Comment: You dont need to foreach over the array to use in_array() look at the manual again

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I just edited the code, I think that If I delete the value after echoing, the user even tho, reloading the page won't recieve the same message duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it an associative array, where the messages are the keys, and the values are boolean flags indicating whether the message has been shown. When a message is added to the array, the value is `false`. Then when the page is loaded, you only show these values, and set their values to `true` to prevent them being shown again.

```
foreach($_SESSION['arrayFolders'] as $message => &$flag){
    if (!$flag) {
        echo $message;
        $flag = true;
    }
}
unset ($flag); // remove the reference to the array element
```

Using the reference variable `&$flag` makes the assignment update the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: Hey @Barmar could you explain a liitle bit more if it's possible the ``&$flag`` wouldn't it be better to be ``is_bool($key)`` and the ``unset($flag)`` it is used to remove the true key? THanks for it, I am getting into the result...

Comment: Array indexes are numbers or strings, so `is_bool($key)` would never be true.

Comment: `unset($flag)` just removes the reference to the array element, it doesn't remove the key.